# How to count overlapping values from a nested list or tuple to print out =

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

```
    alterneuTabelle = [list(value for value in file if value) for file in neueTabelleResult]
```

from SQL i fetch the Data and give to to alterneutabelle, because i wanted to remove the empty strings in neueTabellerResult.

the alterneuTabelle Looks now like:

```
  alterneutabelle[["Area1","Sport", "Math", "Politics" ]["Area2","Sport","Fun","Party"]["Area3","Fun", "Sport", "Math","Politics"]]
```

Note: i have about 40 Area in the SQL database, and those who have overlapping Values with my input will be shows.
that is still ok.

now I want to count the % of how many hits the selected input made with one area and give it back(maybe via appending it to the end)

Expected: My Input is: Party and  Sport.

Output:

["Area1","Sport", "Math", "Politics", 33% ]

["Area2","Sport","Fun","Party",67%]

["Area3","Fun", "Sport", "Math","Politics", 25%]

I want to work with the % later to give a recommendation on where to go.

Problem now i have is that i dont know how to that. i tried to use an if clause and then to count it, but it didnt  work out.

```
   for i in alterneuTabelle:
        for x in i:
            if (x==pick1 or x==pick2 or x==pick3 or x==pick4 or x==pick5):
                b= b+1
                a.append(b)
                b=0
            elif (x==pick1 or x==pick2 or x==pick3 or x==pick4 and x!=pick5):
                b= b+1
                a.append(b)
                b=0
            elif (x==pick1 or x==pick2 or x==pick3 and x!=pick4 and x!=pick5):
                b= b+1
                a.append(b)
                b=0
            elif (x==pick1 or x==pick2 and x!=pick3 and x!=pick4 and x!=pick5):
                b= b+1
                a.append(b)
                b=0
            elif (x==pick1 and x!=pick2 and x!=pick3 and x!=pick4 and x!=pick5):
                b= b+1
                a.append(b)
                b=0
```

should i maybe work with the tuple from neueTabelleResult, and add the percentages before the empty String removal?

any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

```
queries = ["Party", "Sport"]
docs = [["Area1","Sport", "Math", "Politics" ]["Area2","Sport","Fun","Party"]["Area3","Fun", "Sport", "Math","Politics"]]

counts = [0] * len(docs)
for i, doc in enumerate(docs):
    for q in queries:
        counts[i] += doc.count(q)

docs_with_p = [l + [c / (len(l) - 1)] for l, c in zip(docs, count)]
```

will create a new list `docs_with_p` with the percentage (according to the `len` of the sub-list - 1 to remove "Area" from the percentage) appended to the end of each sub-list (document). However, you should probably just make a dictionary.

```
docs_to_p = {l: c / (len(l) - 1) for l, c in zip(docs, count)}
```

as it will be presumably easier to use for whatever comes after this.